# how to compare values from "User defined variables" with values from "JDBC Request" in jMeter

Tags: jdbc, comparison, jmeter

I want to compare(assert maybe) some values from "User defined variables" with values obtained from DB query using "JDBC Request" in jMeter, the thing is after i do the SELECT query i get only the column names and not the values. How can i do this comparison step by step?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, MySQL server has "mysql" database. In this database there is a "help_keyword" table which looks as follows:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> describe help_keyword;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| help_keyword_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name            | char(64)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So if you configure your JDBC Request to select first row as

```
select * from help_keyword limit 1;
```

It'll return the following:

```
help_keyword_id name
0   JOIN
```

For instance you need to assert this `JOIN` keyword. To do so:

Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configuration element and define `KEYWORD` variable with the value of `JOIN`

[image: User Defined Variable]

Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) configured as follows:

- Query Type

  - Select Statement
- Query

  - `select * from help_keyword limit 1;`
- Variable names

  - `id,name`

[image: JDBC Request]

Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of JDBC Request configured as follows:

- Apply to

  - JMeter Variable: `name_1`
- Patterns to Test

  - `${KEYWORD}`

[image: Response Assertion]

Test Plan above will perform whether 1st row of "name" column value equals `JOIN`

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on how JMeter Assertions can be used.

Comment: Can you tell me what "name_1" has to do in this? It can be any name?(it seems with other name is not working, it returns null). Does *_1 mean something?

Comment: See documentation on JDBC Request. `If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up`. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

Answer (score 0):

Use "Response Assertion" for your JDBC request.
Select the below mentioned properties of "Response Assertion":

- **Apply to:** "Jmeter Variable"  e.g. ${value}, where value is User Defined variable.
- **Response field to test:**  "Text Response"
- **Pattern Matching Rules:** As per your requirement.

Hope this will help